# Calendar extender not showing desires dates

Tags: jquery, date, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi i am Using Ajax calendar extender.
My default date should be 01/01/1997 and i  disabled dates after 01/01/1997.
But when i click on textbox with calendar extender ,
todays date is shown  and cannot able to navigate as i have disabled that dates.
[image]
I want the dates  of 1997 to be shown when clicking on calendar.

```
CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate = /*desired date now 01/01/1997*/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

**Example:**

```
txtFromDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(CalendarExtender1.Format);
```

Where **txtFromDate** is the `textbox` control associated with **Calender Extender**